# utmParameters is always empty for a Firebase Dynamic Link

Tags: android, firebase-analytics, firebase-dynamic-links, event-tracking

I've created several dynamic links with UTM parameters using the Firebase console. Yet, the `utmParameters` field is always empty.

By the time the `intent` is received the UTM parameters have been stripped off. We want to use these parameters for additional tracking and decision-making in the app.

Any ideas what could be going wrong here? Thanks

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    Firebase.dynamicLinks
        .getDynamicLink(intent)
        .addOnSuccessListener(this) { pendingDynamicLinkData ->
            var deepLink: Uri? = null
            if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.link

                Timber.tag("XXX").d("UTM :${pendingDynamicLinkData.utmParameters}")
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener(this) { e -> Timber.e(e, "Failed to process Dynamic Link") }
}
```

Comment: Are you adding the utm params to the destination url? In that case they will not be in the pending dynamic link. Ensure that you are setting the umt params on the dynamic link.

Comment: Yes, I set them on the dynamic link

Comment: I have the same issue, I cannot get the utm params in the apps, even though it already collected by the `dynamic_link_*` event. have you found the solutions?

Answer (score 7):

I find the same problem and what solve it for me is start using the method that expects an Uri instead of Intent.

```
intent.data?.let {
    Firebase.dynamicLinks.getDynamicLink(it)
        .addOnSuccessListener(this) {
            ......
}
```

Comment: Worked for me. Now I will check if it's possible to access to the utm params without the dynamic links lib. The app link is accessible but I still don't see the utm params after printing the intent and its extras.

Answer (score 0):

The URI worked for me.
The Java equivalent code:

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().getDynamicLink(getIntent().getData())
```